# React Context Unable to set context

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-context

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import keys from '../../keys'


const getCollection = () => {
    console.log("getCollectionCalled")
    return axios.get(`${keys.url}/collection`)
       .then(data => {
         console.log(data)
         return data
       })
       .catch(err => {
         return {}
       })
}

const SHOP_DATA =  getCollection();
const CollectionsContext = createContext(SHOP_DATA);

export default CollectionsContext;
```

This is the code I am trying to run but context is not setting as per the data from the server, when I am using this in other component like this

```
const collections = useContext(CollectionsContext);
  console.log("COLLECTIONS ", collections)
```

It is consoling it as :

```
COLLECTIONS  Promise {<pending>}__proto__: 
             Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
             [[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Kindly rectify me I am unable to think how may I implement it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you're returning a promise as initial context value, what you need to do is something between these lines:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import keys from '../../keys'

const INITIAL_STATE = {}
const CollectionsContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE)

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${keys.url}/collection`)
      .then(data => setCollection(data))
      .catch(() => setCollection(INITIAL_STATE))
  }, [])

  return (
    <CollectionsContext.Provider value={collection}>
      {children}
    </CollectionsContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useCollection = () => useContext(CollectionsContext)
export default Provider
```

Then you wrap the top level (as high as it's needed, not neccessarily the highest) with the provider:

```
import CollectionsProvider from '.../.../somewhere'

<CollectionsProvider>...rest of components...</CollectionsProvider>
```

In this case, INITIAL_STATE is the value provided until value is undefined or you haven't used Provider. For example, you use useCollection outside of CollectionsProvider.

Comment: Can't I set the context before using it in another file, I am making a file for creating the context then able to use that context anywhere in app. Isn;t that possible to do!

Comment: This is what my example does, but you need the value not the promise